# WHERE column IN CASE type WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm getting syntax error when trying to run the query below but I'd like to know if it's possible to execute something like that? So there is a `CASE` expression inside the `IN`. Following isn't really my query so it may look a bit stupid, but it's just for example.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `category` IN 
    CASE `type` 
        WHEN 'a' THEN ('CAT1','CAT2','CAT3') 
        WHEN 'b' ('CAT4') 
        ELSE ('undefined','n/a')
    END
ORDER BY `category`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's generally much better to use AND/OR instead of CASE in ON and WHERE clauses. See JohnHC's answer!

Answer (score 4):

Use `OR`

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE ( `type` = 'a' and `category` IN  ('CAT1','CAT2','CAT3') )
OR ( `type` = 'b' and `category` IN  ('CAT4') )
or (`type` not in ('a','b') and `category` in ('undefined','n/a'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table`
WHERE  CASE `type`
        WHEN  'a' THEN `category` IN ('CAT1','CAT2','CAT3') 
        WHEN 'b' THEN `category` IN  ('CAT4') 
        ELSE `category` IN ('undefined','n/a')
    END
ORDER BY `category`
```